# undefined reference to 'SetCurrentConsoleFontEx'?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, mingw32

When compiling this code:

```
PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX Font_Info;
//Adjust heights
Font_Info.dwFontSize.X = 9;
Font_Info.dwFontSize.Y = 9;
SetCurrentConsoleFontEx( StdHandle, FALSE, Font_Info);
```

GCC reports

```
undefined reference to 'SetCurrentConsoleFontEx'
```

But MSDN says that the header is `#include<windows.h>`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686200(v=vs.85).aspx

Why? And how to resolve this problem ? THANKS.

PS,

I couldn't find any declaration in `wincon.h` and `windows.h`

Comment: That is a linker errors. Are you linking with the WIN32 libraries? More specifically, the `kernel32` library (as specified in the reference).

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg this one? libkernel32.a? (I am a newbie..:-( )

Comment: Yes, just add `-lkernel32` to the end of the command line when building/linking.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg GCC reports: `error: unknown type name 'PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX'` Why? I have looked up MSDN...

Comment: You turned a linker error into a compiler error.  This is not going well.  Why don't you just leave this one on the shelf until you've mastered the many MinGW quirks?  Which are normally dealt with by you adding the missing parts and checking in a patch, the open source way.  Not exactly newbie material of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would not be the first time a function is missing from MinGW's SDK, and especially not a recent function like [SetCurrentConsoleFontEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is only exposed from Vista onwards.

Your libkernel32.a is too old for it; if you want to use this function from MinGW, you may need to access it dynamically instead.

Comment: I think so. But, where to get latest libkernel32.a ?

Answer (score 0):

Undefiend reference refers to a linkage problem. Definition may be in `windows.h` but you need to link to the appropriate library (Kernel32.lib) to generate final binary.

Comment: GCC reports: error: unknown type name 'PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX' Why? I have looked up MSDN.

Comment: @KVD  Maybe you're missing `Wincon.h`